# Steam Market History Data

Tags: python, python-2.7, steam, steam-web-api

So I have written a short script in python that retrieves an item's market history from steam, and I get a response containing the json data. However, I am having some trouble understanding it. For example, one of the pieces of data I receive is ["Sep 26 2014 01: +0",36.548,"12"]. I originally thought that the "01" might represent the hour, but in the file, there are multiple elements with the same first part of "Sep 26 2014 01: +0". I am also confused as to the meaning of the "12" after. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add your code to the question to help with an answer.

Comment: @Shaun I probably should've avoided tagging this as python. I'm not having any code errors, I just can't seem to make sense of part of this log message, which is the same as what I get when I retrieve the JSON object in the web browser, so I know it's not a code error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The "01" represents the time in UTC, and the "12" represents the volume sold in the hour at that value.

Comment: Where did you find that?  Is there an API document?

Comment: @MarcelWilson I took a piece of recent data, and then went to the actual market and compared it to the graph, and found what matched. I also had to look up the current UTC to get the time.